# Unable to register device for push notification

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm hitting:

> error NSError *   domain: @"com.ibm.mfp.push" - code:
>   5 0x0000000140986740
>
> [0]   (null)  @"NSLocalizedDescription" : @"This version of the
>   MobileFirst client SDK requires a minimal server version greater than
>   IFIX 8.0.0.0-IF201701250919"

When registering device

[image]

I'm using this sample project:
https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PushNotificationsCordova/tree/release80

Comment: What is the exact level of your mfp server and your cordova plugin

Comment: MFP Server version is: Product version: 8.0.0.00-20161122-002317

Comment: cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017021815 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2017012410 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation - Push Notifications"

Comment: @VivinK how to download a particular version of mfp Server and a particular version of cordova-plugin for client side? Seems like my server version and cordova-plugins are out of sync. Is it compulsory to keep all 3 to be the same version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in this [blogpost](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/03/09/8-0-ifix-release/), with the latest iFixes of MFP 8.0 , it is required that the server version be higher than the client SDK version. It is recommended that both the levels be equal. If this is not possible, at least have the client SDK run at a lower version than the server.

For your testing, you should either update the server to the latest version or downgrade your client SDK to the lower version.

To list the available client SDK versions you can use the following commands:

```
npm view cordova-plugin-mfp-push versions

npm view cordova-plugin-mfp versions
```

From this list you can install the specific version of the Cordova plugin using the format:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp@<version id>
```

For example:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp@8.0.2016110713
```

Comment: Thx Vivin... I'm able to register the device now... However, I'm not able to receive the notification from iPad device after a successful message push from MobileFirst console. Is the sample working?

Comment: Able to get the notification on my local server after upgrading to latest MobileFirst Server together with latest plugins... Still figuring why the latest iFix for mfp server is not applied even after a successful update :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030603/ibm-mobilefirst-ifix-doesnt-update-the-version-displayed-in-operations-console

Comment: In a standalone server, merely updating the file system ( using installation manager) is not sufficient. You need to update the server deployment as well:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/appserver/#applying-a-fix-pack-by-using-the-server-configuration-tool

Comment: Thx @Vivin K you are very helpful