# IBM MobileFirst Platform iFix doesn't update the version displayed in Operations Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I've just updated my IBM MobileFirst Platform Server from 8.0.0.00-20160822-2140 with the latest iFix 8.0.0.0-MFPF-Server-IF201702201900

[image]

However, after a successful update, the server is still showing the same old version in the IBM MobileFirst Platform Operations Console.

Does it means it's still not updated with the latest iFix?

[image]

I've double confirmed that the fix is indeed installed:

[image]

Do I need to update those superseded iFix first before upgrading to the latest iFix?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Customers Copy ?

Comment: What is a customer copy? How can I check? I'm not sure which type am I using but I downloaded it from iFix
 https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other+software/IBM+MobileFirst+Platform+Foundation&release=8.0.0.0&platform=All&function=all&source=fc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vivin above is correct.  Installation Manager merely puts the files on disk.  You must now update your database by running the Server Configuration Tool, or whatever method you used when your server was first configured.  Since the version number is stored in the database, the old version number will appear in the Operations Console until the database update is performed.

Comment: Thx @John Gerken, I wasn't aware of this. I have very poor common sense =p

Answer (score 0):

Able to get it to work after running  cd /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/shortcuts
sudo ./configuration-tool.sh again and restart the server. Didn't know there's a need to do so after updating the iFix. Is this common?

[image]

Comment: Now You can download new version from site itself. iFix is just a fixed in previous version.

Comment: This is normal and expected:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/appserver/#applying-a-fix-pack-by-using-the-server-configuration-tool

Answer (score 0):

You can Download the **MobileFirst Developer Kit Installer  (IF20170220-1900)** for **Customer** and **Evaluators** copy direct from 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/
[image]

**Now check Product Version:**

[image]

Comment: but this is for local server instead of a actual linux server right?